# move_base to use map published on a certain topic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm having trouble trying to make my `move_base` constantly subscribe to a certain topic to load current SLAM-made map. There are some related questions here like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/10180/build-map-dynamically-in-slamnot-using-static-map/), [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/155091/move_base-without-map/), [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/49841/navigation-using-real-time-generate-map-without-a-known-map/) but none of them helped.

I mean that I would like `move_base` node to update map it is using with the one that is published to a given topic and periodically updated.

I'm using visual SLAM. I have PCL data but can't use it directly as I have to perform some space clearing operations. Ready to use map is published as a ROS message of type `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` and correctly visualized in rViz.

What's problematic here is that I can successfully use `static_map` loaded from file but I have no idea how to use dynamically published map instead of direct sensor stream.

Here are my current configuration files:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: "map"
  robot_base_frame: "base_link"
  transform_tolerance: 20.0
  update_frequency: 2.0 
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  rolling_window: true 
  always_send_full_costmap: true
  static_map: false
  map_type: costmap
```

Local costmap:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: "odom" 
  robot_base_frame: "base_link"
  transform_tolerance: 10.0 

  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 0.5

  rolling_window: true
  always_send_full_costmap: true
  static_map: false
  map_type: costmap

  # ---- Following most likely replaced by static map layer
  width: 1.0     
  height: 1.0    
  resolution: 0.01
```

Common parameters:

```
plugins: 
#    - {name: static_map,       type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"} 
    - {name: inflation,        type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    - {name: sonar,            type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
```

Static map layer:

```
map_topic: "/map_topic"
first_map_only: false
```

So at the moment I don't use static map layer and everything loads correctly except that blank costmaps are published (global and local). No error is shown.

Otherwise, if I enable static map layer, set global and local costmaps to use rolling window and non-static map `move_base` node is stuck at:

```
[ INFO] [1528620968.885129620]: Using plugin "static_map"
[ INFO] [1528620968.904921357]: Requesting the map...
```

I'm sure that topic name is correct.

In the [static map layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap) there is parameter defined `map_topic` and `first_map_only` but seem not to work as I expected. If I set global and local costmap's parameters as:

```
static_map: true
rolling_window: false
```

and run `map_server` with appropriate file (previously saved map) everything works good. But it's not the way I would like to do it.

Any tips are welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293696/move_base-to-use-map-published-on-a-certain-topic/) by [rayvburn](https://answers.ros.org/users/33779/rayvburn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a conflict in parameter names. I've been trying to load costmap's static layer `static_map` parameters into `move_base/global_costmap/static_map` namespace , but there was a single `static_map` parameter already in `/move_base/global_costmap`.

Also, it's probably better not to put all used plugins into common_costmap parameters but into separate files (for local and global).
What I did in global costmap's .yaml file was renaming namespace from `static_map` to `static_layer` (see question post)

```
global_costmap:
  plugins: 
    - {name: static_layer,       type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  # ... other parameters
```

and then in `move_base's` .launch file:

```
      <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive_mapping_robot_navigation)/config/static_map_params.yaml"
                command="load"
                ns="global_costmap/static_layer" />
```

Hope it will somehow help someone and save his time.

---

Originally posted by [rayvburn](https://answers.ros.org/users/33779/rayvburn/) with karma: 78 on 2018-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madgrizzle](https://answers.ros.org/users/53314/madgrizzle/) on 2020-04-07**:
Is it possible to buy you a cup of coffee?  Thanks for this answer.  It is exactly the problem I was facing and driving me crazy.. until I found this post.